# Users is not associated with LastBookmarks

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Im following Lynda tutorial on cakephp 3 basics and i have encountered on problem. The task was that when you view one user, this users entity must also contain information about his last added bookmark.

So what the guy on tutorial did was:

on bookmarks table i have added one relation hasOne

```
class BookmarksTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('bookmarks');
        $this->displayField('title');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Tags', [
            'foreignKey' => 'bookmark_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'joinTable' => 'bookmarks_tags'
        ]);

        // i have added this line
        $this->hasOne('LastBookmarks', [
            'className' => 'Bookmarks',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
    }
```

And my usersController i have added LastBookmarks in contain array

```
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Bookmarks', 'LastBookmarks']
        ]);

        $this->set('user', $user);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }
```

And the error i'm getting is `Users is not associated with LastBookmarks`
This is a print screen of error which i'm getting when i press view on one user
[image]

How can i overcome my problem? If you need any additional informations, please let me know and provide. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do your find on the `Users` table, so you are missing the association on that table.

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasOne('LastBookmarks');
    }
}
```

This might not be exactly correct for you, but basically the error is telling you that the `Users` table doesn't know what `LastBookmark` is, because it's not associated with it.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Add the correction association that `UsersTable` needs to relate to `LastBookmarksTable`.

Comment: yes you are right. One think, there is no LastBookmarks table... In tutorial there is Bookmarks and Users table. But then somehow guy makes lastbookmark information on user trough $this->hasOne('LastBookmark') code. Any way adding this association on Users table worked for me. Thx

Comment: ehhh now i get it :D the code i added should not be on BookmarksTable but on UsersTable :D Thx man!